# Como ordenar itens com números flutuantes no WHERE

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como posso realizar uma consulta, tendo um número `float`. No banco eu tenho um item com esse numero (3.4), porem quando eu aplico o seguinte código, não esta aparecendo o item com numero (3.4).

```
$numerador = '3.4';
$lisagemMedias = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `medias` WHERE `cat`='".$dadosGerais["cat"]."' AND `subcat`='".$dadosGerais["id"]."' AND `numero`='".$numerador."' ORDER BY numero");
$mediaDados = mysql_fetch_array($lisagemMedias); 
$numeradorPonto = str_replace('.', '-', $mediaDados["numero"]);


echo $dadosGerais["nome"].' '.$numeradorPonto;
```

Gostaria de saber como posso concertar isso de forma que eu possa realizar consulta tanto de números inteiros como (1,2,3). Como números com valores `float` como (1.2, 3.4).

Comment: Você pode tentar colocar uma aspa simples antes desse numerador, como você faz com o id `AND 'numero' = ' ".$numerador." ' `

Comment: já editei eu esqueci de por isso aqui digitei esse código pelo tablete foi mal em todo caso ainda não esta fazendo aparecer o valor com float 3.4

Comment: No seu banco não está salvo com vírgula não?

Comment: Não esta salvo como 3.4 mesmo eu fiz isso no caso quando eu colocar um numero assim o 3-4 ele converte para 3.4 para enviar esse valor a SQL e o tipo na SQL ao invés do int  e float no campo de numero eu não uso varchar e nem char pois não ordena direito em ordem numérica dependendo do que você queira fazer sendo que no meu caso foi necessário o float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme está resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1302270/1518921)

Altere para `decimal` e usa `CAST`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CAST(numero AS DECIMAL) = CAST(101.31 AS DECIMAL);
```

Porém você pode considerar alterar a "coluna" da sua tabela para `DECIMAL`:

```
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN numero decimal(4,2)
```

Recomendo que veja este artigo:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

**Nota:** `DECIMAL` é geralmente considerado o melhor tipo a ser usado quando se lida com valores monetários.

Answer (score 0):

Tente sem as aspas, da seguinte maneira:

```
$lisagemMedias = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `medias` WHERE `cat`='".$dadosGerais["cat"]."' AND `subcat`='".$dadosGerais["id"]."' AND `numero`=".$numerador." ORDER BY numero");
```